# Can I ignore __pycache__ directories in bash-completion and grep?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've ignored `__pycache__` in my `git` repos and in `vi`'s wildmenu. The last place these directories pollute my workflow is when recursively grepping through project files and when using <kbd>tab</kbd> auto-completion on the command line.

Is there a way to configure command-line tools like `grep` and `bash-completion` to universally ignore directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `bash` you can make file globbing drop `__pycache__`, by setting:

```
$ export GLOBIGNORE=__pycache__
```

Now if you issue:

```
$ ls __*
ls: cannot access __*: No such file or directory
```

Also with `bash` You can use the `FIGNORE` environment variable to skip file suffixes. It can be used to somewhat filter the directory...

```
$ mkdir __pycache__
$ export FIGNORE=__pycache__
```

Then when issuing:

`$ ls __`<kbd>tab</kbd>

will complete to

`$ ls __pycache__`

However, if it is prefixed (such as using a path):

`$ ls ./__`<kbd>tab</kbd>

it will not complete.

You can alias `grep` to exlude the `__pycache__` directories:

```
alias grep='grep --exclude-dir="__pycache__"'
```

You could also use Madhavan Kumar's answer to change the completion of `grep` and the other commands you want to filter, but don't forget they will have to be defined in a rc file and sourced after sourcing `bash_completion`, to apply your overrides.

```
FIGNORE
    A colon-separated list of suffixes to ignore when performing filename 
completion (see READLINE below). A filename whose suffix matches one of 
the entries in FIGNORE is excluded from the list of matched filenames. A 
sample value is ".o:~". 

GLOBIGNORE
    A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames to
    be ignored by pathname expansion. If a filename matched by a pathname 
    expansion pattern also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is 
    removed from the list of matches.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the compsec for these commands, to ignore them.

Say, for example, to get the existing compsec, use

```
complete -p grep
```

returns,

```
 complete -F _longopt grep
```

Now add the exclude option to this command as,

```
complete -F _longopt -X '@(__pycache__|more__patterns)' grep
```

You will not see those filenames on tab press